# How to watch a MediaPlayer and get feedback on it's CurrentProgress?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm writing an android app that uses the `MediaPlayer`. I've created a custom `IAudioPlayer` as a wrapper for the MediaPlayer so that I can eventually extend it to iOS.

```
public interface IAudioPlayer
{
    bool IsPlaying { get; }
    void Play(string fileName, int startingPoint);
    void Play(string fileName);
    void Pause();
    void Stop();
    int CurrentPosition();
    bool HasFile();
    void SkipForward(int seconds);
    void SkipBackward(int seconds);
    void SeekTo(int seconds);
}
```

Our app is structured using the Mvvm pattern and is using MvvmCross.

On our FragmentViewModel we've got commands such as `IPlayCommand`, `IStopCommand`, etc.

```
public class HomeFragmentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public HomeFragmentViewModel(IPlayCommand playCommand, 
                                 IStopCommand stopCommand, 
                                 ISkipForwardCommand skipForwardCommand, 
                                 ISkipBackwardCommand skipBackwardCommand)
    {
        _playCommand = playCommand;
        _stopCommand = stopCommand;
        _skipForwardCommand = skipForwardCommand;
        _skipBackwardCommand = skipBackwardCommand;
    }

    private string _playPauseIcon = FontAwesome.icon_play;
    public string PlayPauseIcon
    {
        get { return _playPauseIcon; }
        set { _playPauseIcon = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => PlayPauseIcon); }
    }

    private IPlayCommand _playCommand;
    public IPlayCommand PlayCommand
    {
        get { return _playCommand; }
        set { _playCommand = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => PlayCommand); }
    }

    private IStopCommand _stopCommand;
    public IStopCommand StopCommand
    {
        get { return _stopCommand; }
        set { _stopCommand = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => StopCommand); }
    }

    private ISkipForwardCommand _skipForwardCommand;
    public ISkipForwardCommand SkipForwardCommand
    {
        get { return _skipForwardCommand; }
        set { _skipForwardCommand = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SkipForwardCommand); }
    }

    private ISkipBackwardCommand _skipBackwardCommand;
    public ISkipBackwardCommand SkipBackwardCommand
    {
        get { return _skipBackwardCommand; }
        set { _skipBackwardCommand = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SkipBackwardCommand); }
    }
}
```

On our View we've got buttons that bind to those commands, and all is working as expected.

**However**

Our view also has a `SeekBar` that we're going to use for quick scrubbing by the user. The seekbar needs to do two things...

1. allow the user quickly navigate to the spot that's required (this one "should" be easy
2. automatically update based on the track's current progress (this one I'm stuck on)

How can I write a notifier that triggers every second, and automatically update the seekbar binding? This notifier would need to live in the PCL with the Command Objects so that it can work cross platform. I'm struggling with getting started on this... I'm not sure where to create it or how to wire it up.

Comment: I think the Messenger plugin would be useful here. See the N=9 episode on http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com

Comment: @Kiliman I've almost got something working using the Messenger Plugin. The problem is that my `CurrentProgress()` method. I'm running a `while(true){ }` in my custom watcher to poll the current progress, but it's obviously blocking. I have to figure out how to either signal from the method, or watch without blocking...

Answer (score 1):

> automatically update based on the track's current progress (this one I'm stuck on)

You should be able to do this using a binding to a View property. Here's some pseudo code:

In the ViewModel, add the SeekPosition property:

```
 public double SeekPosition { /* normal INPC get/set */ }
```

In the View:

1. add a property and event pair like:

   ```
    public event EventHandler CurrentPositionChanged;
    public double CurrentPosition
    {
        get { return _mediaPlayer.CurrentPosition; }
        set
        {
            _mediaPlayer.SeekTo(value);
        }
    }
   ```
2. add a timer to fire the `CurrentPositionChanged` event on the UI thread. For Android, create this timer in `OnResume` and destroy it in `OnPause`.
3. add a binding in `OnCreate`:

   ```
    public override void OnCreate(args)
    {
         // normal base call and inflate
         // ...

         var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();
         set.Bind(this).For(v => v.CurrentPosition).To(vm => vm.SeekPosition);
         set.Apply();
    }
   ```

Note that this approach doesn't use a timer in the PCL. This is because other platforms like iOS and Windows shouldn't need the timer - as they should be able to use progress callbacks/events from the media players on those platforms instead.

Comment: I actually started down a path of using the Messenger plugin. I'm really hoping to do this without any code in the View. I'll have the CurrentPosition on the ViewModel and everything else "hopefully" in sharable libraries. I'd actually like to convert it into another MvvmCross plugin eventually (if possible).